# Rails not picking up .yaml.erb fixtures?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, continuous-integration, circleci, circleci-2.0

I'm trying to set up Circle CI for a Rails backend to automate a fair amount of tests, some of the tests are legacy code that uses YAML fixtures with erb tags. I'm using a Ruby 2.6.9, Rails 5.2.6, Circle CI docker image is refusing to parse those files for bad formatting.

> An example of how the fixtures look :
>
> ```
> <% mt = Medtest.new(result: "Positive") %>
> covid19_positive:
>   user: user1
>   medtest_type: COVID-19
>   encrypted_result: <%= mt.encrypted_result %>
>   encrypted_result_iv: <%= mt.encrypted_result_iv %>
>   result_bidx: <%= Medtest.generate_result_bidx("Positive").inspect %>
>   test_date: <%= 10.days.ago.to_s(:db) %>
>   created_at: <%= 10.days.ago.to_s(:db) %>
>   shared: true
> ```
>
> error when running test in Circle CI docker image
>
> ```
> RuntimeError: Wrapped undumpable exception for: ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError: a YAML error occurred parsing /home/circleci/project/test/fixtures/medtests.yml. Please note that YAML must be consistently indented using spaces. Tabs are not allowed. Please have a look at http://www.yaml.org/faq.html
> The exact error was:
>   ArgumentError: must specify a key
>     test/fixtures/medtests.yml:1:in `get_binding'
> ```

I tried taking the erb tags out of the yaml files and just hardcoding the dynamic values instead but that brings forward other issues (pretty much I have to refactor a 1000 tests, line by line if I want to do that). A suggested solution was to use .yaml.erb format for the fixtures instead of .yml format but it seems that Rails is not picking up the fixtures after changing the format! Any ideas on how to deal with this with minimum refactoring?

PS: All tests pass locally on multiple machines without any issues.

Comment: Are you really sure it is not just formatted incorrectly?  Did something slip in via copy & paste or something? Have you indeed verify the yaml is formatted correctly?   https://jsonformatter.org/yaml-formatter

Comment: @RockwellRice that im sure of. all the fixtures load locally without any issues. All test suites pass locally too! :)

Comment: Validate your YAML using circle ci utility https://support.circleci.com/hc/en-us/articles/360006735753-Validating-your-CircleCI-Configuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: turned out it's not a yaml parsing issue, when rails loads fixtures, you can also get argument errors, which if you are using dynamic yaml's can be coming from your models, in my case, it was a missing environment variable that broke the models which in return stopped the fixtures from loading.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).